# Online xcode project (Working together)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, xcode4

I was wondering if Xcode has any possibilities to work on an xcode project from a server.

Like working together on the same xcode project with two people? Kinda like dreamweaver has the possibility to connect to ftp... Would come quite handy.

Didn't found anything on this on stackoverflow or google...

Thnx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has SCM support (CVS, Subversion and Perforce). This is the only way to work on the same project I guess.

Comment: In fact, *use* Git. Far more flexible than Subversion.

Comment: I'm now using Git with dropbox (Github makes your code public). It's working quite ok. Only problem... I can't make a push in xcode, need to do it in terminal. For the rest working ok!

Answer (score 2):

I work with remote developers and we use either git or svn.  Xcode does integrate with repositories but it's not necessary as you can achieve the same thing from the command line.

Using source control will allow multiple developers to work on a single project together.  Both git and svn will merge files.

Answer (score 1):

No, Apple has not provided this in the Xcode software. Nor is there any rumors on implementing this, it would be a nice feature but since Apple also doesn't allow plugins for Xcode we have to wait for Apple to add this ability to the software. This would be a really neat feature, but it could be a long time before we see this.

Comment: @Jos As Others have suggested, you can try SVN or a Code management tool, but beware its not like dreamweavers content management. It will integrate with xcode but I have accidentally overwritten good code doing that before though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GIT (http://git-scm.com/) and use a remote repository, like dropbox o github.

On XCODE4 you can use git, with out any additional plugin